# How do I apply my function to a dataframe such that it creates a new column on the dataframe?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

First, apologies for some awful, illogical, clunky code coming up. I have MINIMAL experience with for loops and functions.

In essence, I want to apply a function to a dataframe. This function provides a value [i] conditional on the values in two of the columns in the dataframe. I then want this value to be populated in a new column, and to align with the row containing the values that generated it.

This is using some already generated model values to create predicted abundance of an animal species.

I have created a fairly awful function, aligning with the known values of the generated model.

Here is an example of the data:

```
structure(list(X = 2:6, x = c(23.69772329, 23.33799932, 24.50995071, 
22.37691419, 31.29742091), y = c(-18.75309389, -18.28537894, 
-19.39926585, -19.23678464, -5.251863724), EVAP_Value = c(502L, 
541L, 750L, 476L, 571L), HFI_Value = c(1, 1, 3.059409052, 2.250018061, 
7), TERMAC_Value = c(605L, 605L, 118L, 605L, 236L), TERMAC_ShortName = 
structure(c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("DAWS2", "EASM", "Marsh", "PV"), class = 
"factor"), 
GLOBCOV_Value = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 140L, 130L), Glob_ShortName = 
structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Grass", "OpBdFrst", "OpNdFrst", 
"Shrub", "VegCrop"), class = "factor"), Unknown_Value = c(527L, 
546L, 488L, 430L, 1020L), Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("BWA", "TZA"), class = "factor"), 
NDVI_mean = c(0.26736562, 0.28850313, 0.328852412, 0.271927773, 
0.364711006), Random_Category = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("Random_Maasai", "Random_Southern"), class = "factor"), 
num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Random", class = "factor")), row.names = 2:6, class = 
"data.frame")
```

For reference, it looks like this:

```
X        x          y EVAP_Value HFI_Value TERMAC_Value
1 1 37.97434  -8.833364       1390  6.000000          601
2 2 23.69772 -18.753094        502  1.000000          605
3 3 23.33800 -18.285379        541  1.000000          605
4 4 24.50995 -19.399266        750  3.059409          118
5 5 22.37691 -19.236785        476  2.250018          605
6 6 31.29742  -5.251864        571  7.000000          236
        TERMAC_ShortName GLOBCOV_Value Glob_ShortName Unknown_Value
1             <NA>            90       OpNdFrst          1038
2               PV            30        VegCrop           527
3               PV            30        VegCrop           546
4            DAWS2            30        VegCrop           488
5               PV           140          Grass           430
6             EASM           130          Shrub          1020
  Location NDVI_mean Random_Category num     ID
1      TZA 0.5356669   Random_Maasai   1 Random
2      BWA 0.2673656 Random_Southern   1 Random
3      BWA 0.2885031 Random_Southern   1 Random
4      BWA 0.3288524 Random_Southern   1 Random
5      BWA 0.2719278 Random_Southern   1 Random
6      TZA 0.3647110   Random_Maasai   1 Random
```

The two columns of interest are the `TERMAC_ShortName` column and the `Glob_ShortName` column. My efforts so far are:

```
 predict.bayes.animal <- function(data){
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "PV") {
           bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.772
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "DAWS2") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 1.24
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "EASM") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.362
  }
         if (data$Glob_ShortName[i] == "VegCrop") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.3497
 }
         if (data$Glob_ShortName[i] == "Grass") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.5978
  }
         if (data$Glob_ShortName[i] == "Shrub") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.2285
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "PV" | data$Glob_ShortName[i] == 
         "VegCrop") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.56
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "DAWS2" | data$Glob_ShortName[i] == 
         "VegCrop") 
 {
            bayes_value[i] <- i + 0.43
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "PV" | data$Glob_ShortName[i] == 
         "Grass") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.49
  }
         if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "EASM" | data$Glob_ShortName[i] == 
         "Shrub") {
            bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.045
  }
   bayes_value
  }

   data["bayes_value"] <- NA
   for (i in 1:nrow(data)) { 
      n <- predict.bayes.animal(data)
      data$bayes_value[i] <- n
  }
```

Expected result is:

```
X        x          y EVAP_Value HFI_Value TERMAC_Value
1 1 23.69772 -18.753094        502  1.000000          605
2 2 23.33800 -18.285379        541  1.000000          605
3 3 24.50995 -19.399266        750  3.059409          118
4 4 22.37691 -19.236785        476  2.250018          605
5 5 31.29742  -5.251864        571  7.000000          236
        TERMAC_ShortName GLOBCOV_Value Glob_ShortName Unknown_Value
1               PV            30        VegCrop           527
2               PV            30        VegCrop           546
3            DAWS2            30        VegCrop           488
4               PV           140          Grass           430
5             EASM           130          Shrub          1020
  Location NDVI_mean Random_Category num     ID   bayes_value
1      BWA 0.2673656 Random_Southern   1 Random       -1.68
2      BWA 0.2885031 Random_Southern   1 Random       -1.68
3      BWA 0.3288524 Random_Southern   1 Random       -1.20
4      BWA 0.2719278 Random_Southern   1 Random       -1.86
5      TZA 0.3647110   Random_Maasai   1 Random       -0.64
```

The actual result so far is "Error in predict.bayes.animal(data) : object 'bayes_value' not found"

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: do you need an extra comma in the `data["bayes_value"]` line? eg `data[, "bayes_value"]`

Comment: I just checked and unfortunately the error stays the same :(. I'm thinking it's probably due to incorrect assignation of "bayes_value" in the function... but I'm not sure how else to assign it.

Comment: how about the `assign` function?

Comment: Still getting the same error. I tried `assign` in the for loop and within the function separately, and then within both, but neither iteration worked. Again could be due to placement though, and it could be that assign is the solution when "bayes_value"/`assign("bayes_value", 1:i)` is placed elsewhere.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Why don't you just return the bayes column, then when you call the function do `data$bayes <-  predict.bayes.animal(data)`

Comment: Ideally, the function would 1) create a new column (or populate a blank one); 2) with values `i` corresponding to the calculations within the function; 3) which are contingent on the unique values in each row within the columns `TERMAC_ShortName` and `Glob_ShortName`

Comment: I'm not seeing anything to make me think that when you do this in your function: `bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.772`, that it knows `bayes_value` is part of `data`. Try switching each of those assignments to `data$bayes_value[i]`.

Comment: The numbers don't seem to make sense, `i` is the row number but for example in the last line you have `data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "EASM" | df$Glob_ShortName[i] == "Shrub"` which should give 5-0.045 = 4.955 but you are saying in your output that it is -0.64? What is `df` and why did it pop up out of nowhere when you start having or conditions?

Comment: @RAB would you suggest the syntax of `if (data$TERMAC_ShortName[i] == "PV") {
    data$bayes_value[i] <- i - 0.772
  }` rather than what it is above?

Comment: @user2738526 thanks for catching that- I changed in my own code but forgot to change here, from an earlier iteration of the function. I'll edit and change to `data` rather than `df`. The way I was using `i` here was intended to be as a place number, but perhaps it would make the most sense to turn it into `0`, if it is calling the row

Comment: Also when the names fit multiple of the conditions, it will only be taking the last one, is that intentional?

Comment: @phalteman thank you for this- it is now returning a result, although it is only returning a result for the first row, and not the subsequent 4. The result is also wrong. I will try changing `i` to `0` as in the above comment, and see whether that works.

Comment: Thank you @user2738526 - that was something else I was unsure about. I was hoping that the code would be building subsequently, i.e. `i` - 0.772 - 0.3497 - 0.56, but it's highly likely that I set it up incorrectly.

Comment: Returning to the `0` rather than `i` - I think this will hamper efforts to build the code subsequently (as in the above, by returning every value back to 0). I'll do some reading into the use of `j` rather than `i`. I have a dim memory that using `j` may work in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is a bit of confusion about exactly what you are trying to do, but would using `dplyr`'s `mutate` (to add new column) and `case_when` (instead of multiple if statements) possibly simplify things? Eg:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(bayes_value = 
                  case_when(TERMAC_ShortName == "PV" ~ -0.772,
                            data$TERMAC_ShortName == "DAWS2"~-1.24,
                            <OTHER CASES HERE>))
```

REVISED:

```
  data %>% mutate(bayes_value = 
                      case_when(TERMAC_ShortName == "PV" ~ -0.772,
                                TERMAC_ShortName == "DAWS2"~-1.24,
                                <OTHER TERMAC_ShortName CASES HERE>
                                T~0)+
                      case_when(Glob_ShortName == "Grass"~-0.5978,
                                <OTHER Glob CASES HERE>
                                T~0)+
                      case_when(TERMAC_ShortName == "PV" | Glob_ShortName== "VegCrop"~-0.56,
                                <OTHER Combined CASES HERE>
                                T~0))
```

Comment: Oh this won't work if you want to add all conditions that are met together.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly the bones of what I want. And much more elegant than what I was attempting. (and apologies for the confusion)

Comment: Yes, I saw, but it seems to me it would be possible to do it somehow within that format- I'm sure something could be nested within it. I'll keep fiddling around with it, but I think that this is a great step in the right direction.

Comment: I've revised it so that it takes the sum of a condition for TERMAC_ShortName, Glob_ShortName and the combined  condition so hopefully that works

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I've checked and the numbers are a little off but I'm sure that's to do with some other odd issue, and not necessarily this code itself. I'll keep playing with it!